# arima function summary returns In training accuracy(object, test, d, D) : test elements must be within sample

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I used arima function for quarterly time series and get this warning.
(It worked in the beginning pretty well but then I don't know what problem caused this)

final is a dataframe with Value column consisting of numeric.

```
ar1 = arima(final$Value,order=c(1,0,0))
summary(ar1)
```

> Call: arima(x = final$Value, order = c(1, 0, 0))
>
> Coefficients:
> ar1  intercept
> 0.9879     7.3593 s.e.  0.0118     0.5308
>
> sigma^2 estimated as 0.01265:  log likelihood = 108.45,  aic = -212.89
>
> Training set error measures:
> ME RMSE MAE MPE MAPE Training set NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN Warning message: In trainingaccuracy(object, test, d, D) :   test
> elements must be within sample

This happens to every arima function I tried modelling.
With this results I tried forecast function and I get:

```
autoplot(forecast(ar1))
```

> Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

I think something is wrong with my series but I don't understand what's wrong and why it did work fine initially.

Here is the series I used:

> 6.402755 6.447487 6.440739 6.444629 6.325880 6.213987 6.320138 6.221430 6.113566 6.131823 6.198132 6.280816 6.376518 6.682233 6.860274 6.969989 7.313399 7.299082 7.200292 6.975704 6.987592 7.093687 7.008988 6.878341 6.921279 6.885113 6.669485 6.646369 6.672451 6.683375 6.862668 6.971302 7.066513 6.982558 7.000745 6.947200 6.904141 6.907989 6.931114 6.840149 6.959360 7.010516 6.945923 6.997652 7.089783 7.128890 7.243348 7.185718 7.219598 7.340743 7.195484 7.007752 7.032095 7.112150 7.088555 7.044311 7.022457 7.034391 7.050923 7.005283 7.043774 7.097419 7.081782 6.989133 7.088950 7.173351 7.040893 6.990646 7.051991 7.142320 7.203468 7.277060 7.474889 7.554938 7.605872 7.711254 7.856296 7.919240 8.079298 8.137185 8.287493 8.272564 8.222417 8.325414 8.409447 8.473709 8.440126 8.427812 8.264590 8.335643 8.153812 7.567009 7.389719 7.591073 7.760976 7.851489 7.842401 7.827830 7.800251 7.911325 7.966901 7.934157 7.743143 7.539573 7.661231 7.593415 7.621503 7.713353 7.802358 7.778535 7.790057 7.850082 7.857232 7.826338 7.751009 7.687094 7.764962 7.853477 7.773990 7.785429 7.685640 7.709135 7.727118 7.827995 7.921841 8.023987 8.078377 8.120489 8.159005 8.131687 8.108646 8.037131 8.001428 8.024686 7.994422 8.048138 7.937257 7.696907 7.710174 7.787749 8.016172 8.121493 8.176831 8.238139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearly using the forecast package already. So use `Arima` from the forecast package, not `arima` from the stats package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It took me hours until I post it here. The problem caused from the package TSA. Now, I used "forecast" package and "stats" package and they work fine and give same results.